# HtmlAgilityPack return Text with wrong Encoding

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I receive a text like this in my program

```
K&#253; Sinh Tr&#249;ng&#160;  - (2019)
```

Which is wrong and should be as follows

```
Ký Sinh Trùng  - (2019)
```

I used the following code but nothing happened

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(nodes.InnerText);
var myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

how can i fix this?

Update: Full Code:

```
HtmlWeb Webget = new HtmlWeb();

var docx = await Webget.LoadFromWebAsync(@"https://isubtitles.org/search?kwd=parasite");

var items = docx.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='movie-list-info']");

foreach (var node in items)
 {
   var name = node?.SelectSingleNode(".//div/div[2]/h3/a");
   var xxxx = name?.InnerText;
   

   byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xxxx);
   var myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
   Debug.WriteLine(myString);
   return;
 }
```

Comment: Those characters appear to be HTML encoded. I would double check whether the source has these HTML encoded characters to determine whether HtmlAgilityPack is to blame.

Comment: There's no problem at all. `&#253;` is the HTML-encoded form of `ý`, not UTF8. Browsers will display it just fine. This page is UTF8, which is why it can display `Ký Sinh Trùng` or `Αυτό Εδώ` without requiring explicit ... HTML encoding

Comment: UTF8 specifies how text is converted to bytes. It doesn't specify any kind of escape sequences. It's no different to ASCII/Latin1 in that regard. Almost all web sites use UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just HTML encoded text. It's fine. If you need to decode it, then:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(theHtmlEncodedString)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=net-5.0

or (if you have `System.Web` loaded):

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(theHtmlEncodedString)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-5.0

Comment: thank you it is now worked, one more question: If the text is not encoded, does it not cause a problem?

Comment: @karma Only if it coincidentally contains escape sequences such as `&#160;`, `&lt;` etc. This seems unlikely.